# Laravel 4.2 auth:attempt fails

Tags: authentication, laravel

I can't find this website and I can't figure out what is wrong with my code.

I am trying to  get `true` for `var_dump(Auth::attempt())`, but it is always `false`.
This is my controllers method:

```
public function vartotojoPrisijungimoForma(){
    $view = View::make('vartotojai.vartotojoPrisijungimoForma',
    array('title'=>'Vartotojo Prisijungimas'));

    var_dump(Auth::attempt(array('vardas'=>'aaaaa','pw'=>'aaaaa')));

    return $view;
}
```

In my database the username is stored as `vardas` and password as `pw`

My auth.php file looks like this:

```
<?php

return array(
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => 'Vartotojai',
    'table' => 'vartotojai',

    'reminder' => array(
        'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',
        'table' => 'password_reminders',
        'expire' => 60,
),

);
```

And the model file which is Vartotojai.php, looks like this:

```
<?php 
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Vartotojai extends ModeliuBaze implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
    protected $table = 'vartotojai'; 
    public $timestamps = false; 

    protected static $rules = array( 
        'vardas'=>'required|unique:vartotojai|min:4|regex:/[a-zA-Z]$/',
        'pw'=>'required|alpha_num|between:4,8|confirmed',
        'pw_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:4,8'
    );

    protected static $messages = array( 
        'required' => ':attribute laukelis tuscias!',
        'min'=> ':attribute laukelyje galimas minimalus(:min) simboliu kiekis!',
        'between' => ':attribute laukelis gali buti nuo :min - :max simboliu intervale!',
        'vardas.regex'=> ':attribute turi atitikti siuos simbolius (a-zA-Z)',
        'unique'=> 'Jau vartotojas su tokiu vardu uzregistruotas!',
        'alpha_num'=>':attribute laukelyje galima rasyti tik skaicius ir raides!',
        'confirmed'=>'Nesutampa slaptazodziai!'
    );

    protected $hidden = array('password');

    public function getAuthIdentifier(){
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getAuthPassword(){
        return $this->password;
    }
    public function getRememberToken(){
        return $this->remember_token;
    }
    public function setRememberToken($value){
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }
    public function getRememberTokenName(){
        return 'remember_token';
    }
    public function getReminderEmail(){
        return $this->email;
    }
    }
```

I tried to check Hash:

```
    public function vartotojoPrisijungimoForma(){
        $view = View::make('vartotojai.vartotojoPrisijungimoForma',
        array('title'=>'Vartotojo Prisijungimas'));
        $pw = Vartotojai::find('5');

        var_dump(Auth::attempt(array('vardas'=>'aaaaa','pw'=>'aaaaa')));
        var_dump(Hash::check('aaaaa',$pw->pw));
        return $view;
        }
```

And hash check shows true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to change your password field from 'pw' to 'password' in your database. Laravel validates the credentials with 'password'.

OR

You could change this function to:

```
public function getAuthPassword(){
    return $this->pw;
}
```

Then your attempt function should be:

```
var_dump(Auth::attempt(array('vardas'=>'aaaaa','password'=>'aaaaa')));
```